# Are strtol, strtod unsafe?

Tags: c, constants, std, c-strings, const-char

It seems that `strtol()` and `strtod()` effectively allow (and force) you to cast away constness in a string:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  const char *foo = "Hello, world!";
  char *bar;
  strtol(foo, &bar, 10); // or strtod(foo, &bar);
  printf("%d\n", foo == bar); // prints "1"! they're equal
  *bar = 'X'; // segmentation fault
  return 0;
}
```

Above, I did not perform any casts myself. However, `strtol()` basically cast my `const char *` into a `char *` for me, without any warnings or anything. (In fact, it wouldn't allow you to type `bar` as a `const char *`, and so forces the unsafe change in type.) Isn't that really dangerous?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would guess that because the alternative was worse.  Suppose the prototype were changed to add `const`:

```
long int strtol(const char *nptr, const char **endptr, int base);
```

Now, suppose we want to parse a non-constant string:

```
char str[] = "12345xyz";  // non-const
char *endptr;
lont result = strtol(str, &endptr, 10);
*endptr = '_';
printf("%s\n", str);  // expected output: 12345_yz
```

But what happens when we try to compile this code?  A compiler error!  It's rather non-intuitive, but you can't implicitly convert a `char **` to a `const char **`.  See the [C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.17) for a detailed explanation of why.  It's technically talking about C++ there, but the arguments are equally valid for C.  In C/C++, you're only allowed to implicitly convert from "pointer to *type*" to "pointer to `const` *type*" at the highest level: the conversion you can perform is from `char **` to `char * const *`, or equivalently from "pointer to (pointer to `char`)" to "pointer to (`const` pointer to `char`)".

Since I would guess that parsing a non-constant string is far more likely than parsing a constant string, I would go on to postulate that `const`-incorrectness for the unlikely case is preferable to making the common case a compiler error.

Comment: But C++ doesn't prevent you from overloading the function: you could have `long int strtol(char *nptr, char **endptr, int base);` *and* `long int strtol(const char *nptr, const char **endptr, int base);`: this fixes your compile error. Indeed, the standard does this for other such functions, like `strchr` and `strstr`,

Comment: You could refer to the C FAQ web site [What's the difference between `const char *p`, `char const *p`, and `char * const p`?](http://c-faq.com/ansi/constptrconst.html) and, more particularly, [Why can't I pass a `char **` to a function which expects a `const char **`?](http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html) instead of the C++ FAQ, though I'm not wholly convinced the explanations are easy to understand.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, and other functions have the same "const-laundering" issue (for instance strchr, strstr, all that lot).

For precisely this reason C++ adds overloads (21.4:4): the function signature `strchr(const char*, int)` is replaced by the two declarations:

```
const char* strchr(const char* s, int c);
      char* strchr(      char* s, int c);
```

But of course in C you can't have both const-correct versions with the same name, so you get the const-incorrect compromise.

C++ doesn't mention similar overloads for strtol and strtod, and indeed my compiler (GCC) doesn't have them. I don't know why not: the fact that you can't implicitly cast `char**` to `const char**` (together with the absence of overloading) explains it for C, but I don't quite see what would be wrong with a C++ overload:

```
long strtol(const char*, const char**, int);
```

Comment: stlport provides this overload (and some others).

Answer (score 1):

The 'const char *' for the first argument means that `strtol()` won't modify the string.

What you do with the returned pointer is your business.

Yes, it could be regarded as a type safety violation; C++ would probably do things differently (though, as far as I can tell, ISO/IEC 14882:1998 defines `<cstdlib>` with the same signature as in C).

Comment: C++ does define strtol (and everything else in cstdlib) with the same signature as C, but not everything in cstring and cwchar.

Answer (score 1):

I have a compiler that provides, when compiling in C++ mode:

```
extern "C" {
long int strtol(const char *nptr, const char **endptr, int base);
long int strtol(char *nptr, char **endptr, int base);
}
```

Obviously these both resolve to the same link-time symbol.

EDIT: according to the C++ standard, this header should not compile. I'm guessing the compiler simply didn't check for this. The definitions did in fact appear as this in the system header files.