# Are string literals const?

Tags: c, string, constants, literals

Both GCC and Clang do not complain if I assign a string literal to a `char*`, even when using lots of pedantic options (`-Wall -W -pedantic -std=c99`):

```
char *foo = "bar";
```

while they (of course) do complain if I assign a `const char*` to a `char*`.

Does this mean that string literals are considered to be of `char*` type? Shouldn't they be `const char*`? It's not defined behavior if they get modified!

And (an uncorrelated question) what about command line parameters (ie: `argv`): is it considered to be an array of string literals?

Comment: If you want it to raise a warning, use `-Wwrite-strings`. The equivalent is set in g++

Answer (score 26, accepted):

They are of type `char[N]` where `N` is the number of characters including the terminating `\0`. So yes you can assign them to `char*`, but you still cannot write to them (the effect will be undefined).

Wrt `argv`: It points to an array of pointers to strings. Those strings are explicitly modifiable. You can change them and they are required to hold the last stored value.

Comment: +1 -- note that that is their type, but you must treat them as if they were `const` (or the undefined behavior/access violation fairy will pay you a visit)

Comment: @Billy: don't you see this as somehow inconsistent? Otherwise the OP wouldn't need to ask the question at all.

Comment: @Billy: IMHO the compatibility reasons don't justify such a "feature". People keep getting crashes when code is compiled on a different platform, without a visible warning.

Comment: @Vlad: I didn't write the standard(s) :P

Comment: @Billy: I've got a faint hope that the C++ standard committee members read StackOverflow.

Comment: @Vlad the c++ committee already banned the string literal to `char*` conversion. It's becoming ill-formed to do such a thing in C++0x.

Comment: @Vlad: You'd have to convince the C standards committee to do it too (After all, the change made in C++ was mirrored when C99 added `const` to C)

Comment: C had `const` since C89. It wasn't added to C99.

Comment: They appear to be somewhere in between `char [N]` and `const char[N]`.  See the experiments in the answer I've just added here.  (Perhaps this is something that has changed in C++11?)

Comment: (Sorry, I've only just noticed this question is tagged as `c`, not `c++`.  Maybe my answer isn't so relevant to this question after all!)

Answer (score 10):

For completeness sake the [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)(*C89 and C11 have similar wording*) in section `6.4.5` *String literals paragraph 5* says:

> [...]a byte or code of **value zero is appended** to each multibyte character sequence that results from a string literal or literals. The multibyte character sequence is then used to initialize an **array of static storage duration and length just sufficient to contain the sequence.** For character string literals, the array elements have **type char**, and are initialized with the individual bytes of the multibyte character sequence;[...]

So this says a *string literal* has static storage duration(*lasts the lifetime of the program*) and it's type is `char[]`(not `char *`) and its length is the size of the string literal with an appended zero. *Paragraph 6` says:

> If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.

So attempting to modify a *string literal* is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) regardless of the fact that they are not `const`.

With respect to `argv` in section `5.1.2.2.1` *Program startup paragraph 2* says:

> If they are declared, the parameters to the main function shall obey the following
>   constraints:
>
> [...]
>
> -The parameters argc and argv and the strings pointed to by the argv array shall be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program
>   startup and program termination.

So `argv` is not considered an array of string literals and it is ok to modify the contents of `argv`.

Answer (score 6):

Using `-Wwrite-strings` option you will get:

```
warning: initialization discards qualifiers from pointer target type
```

Irrespective of that option, GCC will put literals into read-only memory section, unless told otherwise by using `-fwritable-strings` (however this option has been removed from recent GCC versions).

Command line parameters are not const, they typically live on the stack.

Answer (score 5):

(Sorry, I've only just noticed this question is tagged as `c`, not `c++`.  Maybe my answer isn't so relevant to this question after all!)

String literals are not quite `const` or `not-const`, there is a special strange rule for literals.

(**Summary**:  Literals can be taken by reference-to-array as `foo( const char (&)[N])` and cannot be taken as the non-const array.  They *prefer* to decay to `const char *`.  So far, that makes it seem like they are `const`.  *But* there is a special legacy rule which allows literals to decay to `char *`.  See experiments below.)

(Following experiments done on clang3.3 with `-std=gnu++0x`.  Perhaps this is a C++11 issue?  Or specific to clang?  Either way, there is something strange going on.)

At first, literals appears to be `const`:

```
void foo( const char  * ) { std::cout << "const char *" << std::endl; }
void foo(       char  * ) { std::cout << "      char *" << std::endl; }

int main() {
        const char arr_cc[3] = "hi";
        char arr_c[3] = "hi";

        foo(arr_cc); // const char *
        foo(arr_c);  //       char *
        foo("hi");   // const char *
}
```

The two arrays behave as expected, demonstrating that `foo` is able to tell us whether the pointer is `const` or not.  Then `"hi"` selects the `const` version of `foo`.  So it seems like that settles it: literals are `const` ... aren't they?

*But*, if you remove `void foo( const char  * )` then it gets strange.  First, the call to `foo(arr_c)` fails with an error at compile time.  That is expected.  But the literal call (`foo("hi")`) works via the non-const call.

So, literals are "more const" than `arr_c` (because they prefer to decay to the `const char *`, unlike `arr_c`.  But literals are "less const" than `arr_cc` because they are willing to decay to `char *` if needed.

(Clang gives a warning when it decays to `char *`).

**But what about the decaying?  Let's avoid it for simplicity.**

Let's take the arrays by reference into foo instead.  This gives us more 'intuitive' results:

```
void foo( const char  (&)[3] ) { std::cout << "const char (&)[3]" << std::endl; }
void foo(       char  (&)[3] ) { std::cout << "      char (&)[3]" << std::endl; }
```

As before, the literal and the const array (`arr_cc`) use the const version, and the non-const version is used by `arr_c`.  And if we delete `foo( const char  (&)[3] )`, then we get errors with both `foo(arr_cc);` and `foo("hi");`.  In short, if we avoid the pointer-decay and use reference-to-array instead, literals behave as if they are `const`.

**Templates?**

In templates, the system will deduce `const char *` instead of `char *` and you're "stuck" with that.

```
template<typename T>
void bar(T *t) { // will deduce   const char   when a literal is supplied
    foo(t);
}
```

So basically, a literal behaves as `const` at all times, except in the particular case where you directly initialize a `char *` with a literal.

Answer (score 2):

In both C89 and C99, string literals are of type `char *` (for historical reasons, as I understand it). You are correct that trying to modify one results in undefined behavior. GCC has a specific warning flag, [-Wwrite-strings](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.2/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wno_002dwrite_002dstrings-365) (which is not part of `-Wall`), that will warn you if you try to do so.

As for `argv`, the arguments are copied into your program's address space, and can safely be modified in your `main()` function.

**EDIT**: Whoops, had `-Wno-write-strings` copied by accident. Updated with the correct (positive) form of the warning flag.

Comment: String literals are array types (`char [N]`), not pointer types (`char *`); refer to **6.4.5 String Literals** in n1256.

Answer (score 2):

Johannes' answer is correct concerning the type and contents. But in addition to that, yes, it is undefined behavior to modify contents of a string literal.

Concerning your question about `argv`:

> The parameters argc and argv and the
>   strings pointed to by the argv array
>   shall be modifiable by the program,
>   and retain their last-stored values
>   between program startup and program
>   termination.

Answer (score 2):

String literals have *formal* type `char []` but *semantic* type `const char []`. The purists hate it but this is generally useful and harmless, except for bringing lots of newbies to SO with "WHY IS MY PROGRAM CRASHING?!?!" questions.

Comment: Makes me curious, do you have an example for this being useful? I mean beyond this backwards compatibility idea, which I guess is less and less relevant?

Comment: Sometimes you want a `char *` instead of a `const char *` for iterating over a string, especially if you'll be passing a pointer to it to a function like `strtol`. It's less a matter of backwards compatibility and more a matter of `const` sometimes being a pain. Of course most of the time in cases like this I have to deal with non-literal strings too and just cast away the `const`...

Comment: @R.. I don't see the issue with iterating over a `const char *` or even passing it to `strtol()`. It's not a `const char const *` after all.

Comment: @morty: `strtol` takes `char **`, not `const char **`, for its `endptr` argument. Likewise for related functions. If you have a `const char *p`, you can't pass `&p` to `strtol`; instead you have to copy the value to a `char *tmp` (using a cast to remove the `const` from the pointed-to type), pass `&tmp`, and then copy the  result back.

Comment: In particular note that you **cannot** pass `(char **)&p` here; doing so results in undefined behavior (aliasing violation).

Comment: @R..: Point taken. But I'm not sure about the undefined behavior. Before we get too off topic, I'll just add some references: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34767233/how-do-you-implement-strtol-under-const-correctness https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993700/are-strtol-strtod-unsafe

Comment: Having string literal non-constant is helpful when calling functions where a programmer didn't declare a parameter const when it could have been.  I expect most libraries have corrected this issue by now, but the language definition won't change for fear of breaking legacy code.  C++ does make string literals constant.

Answer (score 1):

They are const char*, but there is a specific exclusion for assigning them to char* for legacy code that existed before const did. And the command line arguments are definitely not literal, they are created at run-time.

Comment: Not sure why you got downvotes.  I've done some experiments to confirm that they are not quite const or non-const.  I'll post my own answer.

Comment: This is incorrect.  They are not const in C, but are in C++.  They aren't generally writable as noted by others, but they don't behave as constants.  There are some weird things you can't do, like 'case "abc"[2]:' in C, but you can in C++ where string literals are constant.  This can make a big difference with some macros.