# In-Place String Reverse in C

Tags: c, string, reverse, in-place

I am trying to learn the fundamentals of C, but I cannot figure out why this code doesn't work.  The while loop in reverse() causes a bus error.  I found almost identical code in a programming interview book as a valid solution, but neither this nor other similar methods I have seen posted here work for me without a bus error.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverse(char* str) {
 char* end = str;
 char tmp = 0;
 if(str) {
  while(*end) {
   end++;
  }
  --end;
  while(end>str) {
   tmp = *end;
   *end-- = *str;
   *str++ = tmp;
  }
 }
}

int main() {
 char* a = "12";
 puts(a);
 reverse(a);
 puts(a);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493139/are-string-literals-const and many other questions (like at least once a week) on SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to reverse a constant literal string, which is read only.  Change the declaration of `a` in `main` to `char a[] = "12";` to make it a writable char array instead

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to change a string literal which leads to undefined behavior.

Change

```
char* a = "12";
```

to

```
char a[] = "12";
```

Answer (score -2):

Because `end` and `str` point to the same memory location -> they're two different names of the same object. You can avoid using two variables:

```
char foo[20] = "abcdefghi", tmp;
int counter = 0, length = strlen(foo);

for(counter, counter < length / 2; counter++) {
    tmp = foo[counter];
    foo[counter] = foo[length - counter];
    foo[length - counter] = tmp;
}
```

Comment: "object"?  This is C!  (Anyway, `end` and `str` only point to the same location for a couple lines of code.)

Comment: That is missing the point of the in situ reverse: Use two pointers that work within the string buffer. Low level stuff, sure; but it should be efficient and fast.

Comment: @ladenedge: "Object" is the correct word as used in the C language standard.

Comment: @R.: well shut my mouth. "object: region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent values."  Thanks for the correction!