# error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘const char*’

Tags: c++, printf

I have a C++ Program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main (){
    char x [10] = "abc";
    system (sprintf ("mkdir ", "%s", x));    //error happens here, can't 
                                             //convert int to const char*
    return 0;
}
```

results in:

```
sys.c:8:37: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘const char*’
```

Where am I converting an int to a char?

Comment: Look up the documentation on `sprintf`.

Comment: @chris I looked here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/

Comment: @chris HUH, I realize now, I had NOT read that page "carefully"! `str - Pointer to a buffer where the resulting C-string is stored.`

Comment: Besides the answers you got to your question, it seems that your are compiling this as C++ but your question is tagged C. Generally it is not a good idea do mix these like that, there are subtle differences between the two languages that *will* bite you one day or another.

Comment: @JensGustedt yes, I know, but sprintf is a part of C, hence the tag. :)

Comment: @AnishaKaul I you want to use sprintf in C++, you should include <cstdio> instead of <stdio.h>, to make the difference clear. Also, since sprintf is de-facto part of C++, and you use C++, the question should be tagged C++ instead of C. Also, I doubt that you need <stdlib.h> in the code you posted, and if you do, use <cstdlib> instead.

Comment: sprintf Upon successful return, these functions return the number of characters printed so its int U are trying

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin Thanks for the help. Please edit the question as you like it.

Comment: @AnishaKaul I've just retagged it. I won't change the code because of possible references :) Also, regarding `system` you should read http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/11153/

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin I have now removed the traces of c++ from the question making it solely focus on sprintf. Is it okay now?

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin thanks for the link. but, I reverted it back to full C.

Comment: @AnishaKaul wait, are we talking C or C++ now?

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin Well, about sprintf in C. :) Doesn't sprintf behave same way in C and c++?

Comment: @AnishaKaul I was asking because the errors you got initially showed that you compiled the code as C++ :) also, see my answer below for more information on the snprintf family

Comment: Apart from obvious c/c++ confusion, I can't see any reason to close this question as "too localized". Very surprised with the close votes on a well asked question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

system expects a const char * as input, whereas sprintf returns an int. This is the problem which is leading your error. Also, the first argument of sprintf must be a writable buffer of sufficient size.

Comment: Thanks for the great hint. The other answer is now deleted. Can you add the same info here?

Comment: I think Krishnabhadra made has made up very well for the deleted answer. : )

Answer (score 3):

I know that the question has been answered already, but I wanted to share another approach to this, and it's too verbose for a comment :)

short example:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    char x[] = "yourdirectory";
    /* len will contain the length of the string that would have been printed by snprintf */
    int len = snprintf(0, 0, "mkdir %s", x);

    /* casting the result of calloc to (char*) because we are in C++ */
    char *buf = (char*)calloc(len + 1, sizeof(char)); 
    /* fail if the allocation failed */
    if(!buf)
        return -1;

    /* copy to buffer */
    snprintf(buf, len + 1, "mkdir %s", x);

    /* system is evil :( */
    system(buf);

    return 0;
}
```

since snprintf returns the number of characters that would have been printed, giving it a length of 0 will tell you how large a buffer you have to allocate for the command.

this code will also work with arbitrary directories given by a user and will not suffer from input truncation of buffer overruns.

Take care :)

EDIT: of course, system is still evil and should never be used in "real" code ;)

Answer (score 1):

From [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) documentation

> ### sprintf
>
> ```
> int sprintf ( char * str, const char * format, ... );
> ```
>
> sprintf() write formatted data to string.
>
> Composes a string with the same text that would be printed if format
>   was used on printf, but instead of being printed, the **content is
>   stored as a C string in the buffer pointed by str**.
>
> **str** -
>   **Pointer to a buffer where the resulting C-string is stored**. The buffer should be large enough to contain the resulting string.

`sprintf` writes to the first argument, and in your case the first argument is a [string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493139/are-string-literals-const) .

Also as other answer points out, sprintf returns `int` and `system()` [expects](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) `const char*`

Comment: I realized that late, sorry.