# Compile Time Error vs Run Time Error

Tags: c++, c

I am confused why compiler gives

```
const char s[]="hello";
s[2]='t';                 // Compile Time Error

char *t = "hello";
*(t+2)='u';              // Run time Error
```

I guess in both case the compiler should give compile time error. Can anyone tell me particular reason for this to be this way?

Comment: *"I guess in both case the compiler should give compile time error."* - It should, but how could it? You're assigning a value to a non-const object, which is a perfectly legal operation. How should the compiler know `t` points to a const object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first case, you are writing to a `const` and the compiler notices that and can reject that.

In the second case, `t` is a pointer to a non-const `char`, so you can dereference it and write at `*(t+2)`. However, since `t` is initialized with a pointer to a read-only segment, you are getting a segmentation violation at runtime.

You could painfully configure your linker to put all data in writable segments. This is ugly and non standard.

P.S. Some sophisticated static analyzers (maybe [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/)) might catch both errors without running the program. One could also imagine extending GCC e.g. with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) to add such checks (but this is non-trivial work, and it might be hard to get funded for it).

Answer (score 6):

Backwards compatibility.

You can't modify a const char. That much is obvious.

What isn't obvious is that the type of a string literal is actually a pointer to constant characters, not a pointer to characters. The second declaration, actually, therefore has a wrong type. This is supported, however, for historical reasons.

---

Note that the above is a bit of a lie. Rather than pointers, string literals are actually `char[]` types.

In particular, the type of a string literal is a `char[]` rather than a `const char[]` in C89 and C99 [and I think C11, not sure though]. It's not *actually* wrong then, but the data is stored in a read only segment, so it's undefined behavior to try to write to it.

---

Also, for what it's worth, you can use `-Wwrite-strings` with gcc (g++ already includes it) to be warned of this.

---

More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493139/are-string-literals-const) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2245983/567864).

Comment: This is the key point - the second declaration doesn't really make sense, but is allowed.

Comment: I won't say that the second declaration is wrongly typed. There are cases where a cast from a `const` to a non-const data makes sense.

Comment: Just for the record, this conversion is no longer supported in C++.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Was just looking that up. Couldn't remember if strings are (correctly) `const char[]` in C++ :).

Answer (score 3):

When you do: `char *t = "hello";` then **t** is a pointer that points to a memory that is in the code part, so you can't change it. Because it's *read-only*, you're getting segmentation fault at runtime.

When you do: `const char s[]="hello";` then **s** is an array of chars that are *on the stack*, but it's `const`, so you can't change it and you get a compilation error (The compiler knows it is *const* so he doesn't allow you to change it).

Using `const` when you don't want your String to be changed is good because this arise a compilation error, which is a way better than a run time error.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following series of statements:

```
char *t = "hello";
char s[5];
t = s;
*(t+2)='u';
```

This series of statements will give no run time error, because the statement `*(t+2)='u';` is not invalid. It is trying to modify a const (read-only) memory location in your case, but the compiler has no way of knowing whether an access violation will occur.