# Why does the ternary operator const my strings?

Tags: c++, arduino, constants

I am writing some code for a graphical LCD driven by an ATmega328, using the Arduino build chain with Stino as my IDE. I have a function which formats and displays a number with a label. This is the function:

```
void displayNumber(float value, char* label)
```

I realise that both parameters could be `const`ed, but to maintain compatibility with some other code, they are like this.

If I call the function as follows:

```
displayNumber(externalTemp, "MAX");
```

It works fine. I understand string literals behave strangely in that they can't be modified (undefined behaviour) but they are not declared as `const char*` but `char*`.

If I try using the ternary operator to pass an argument to the function:

```
displayNumber(externalTemp, animate10s?"MAX":"MIN");
```

I get a compiler error:

> invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*'

Why is the ternary operator `const`ing my string?

The compiler specifically used is avr-gcc/avr-g++ version 4.3.2, the one bundled with Arduino Beta 1.5.6-r2.

Comment: It isn't. They started out that way.

Comment: Really? This suggests otherwise http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493139/are-string-literals-const and why is there a change in behaviour when not using the ternary operator?

Comment: Could you specify which compiler you are using? I am guessing `avr-gcc`.

Comment: Yes, avr-gcc/g++ - added to question.

Comment: @Cybergibbons That question is about C, not C++. The rules are different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is (or was until recently) a deprecated conversion from string literal to `char *` (without the const it would normally have),  which is what lets the simple call work.

The ternary expression is not a string literal, so the conversion cannot be applied to it.

(Your best solution would be to make sure the function parameter is properly declared as taking `const char *`.)

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to force a string literal be dealt with as const so that strong type checking can be used?

Comment: @Cybergibbons You can try to make the `deprecated-writable-strings` warning into an error with `-Werror=deprecated-writable-strings`.