# How to reallocate memory for a read-only string?

Tags: c, string, malloc, realloc

I know this use-case might sound a bit strange, but I need to understand if it is possible to do something similar to this.

This is my code, and it causes crash on `Aborted (core dumped)`:

```
char *my_str = "Hello World";
my_str = realloc(my_str, 50);
```

-Can you please help me to understand why it crashes?

-Is there a standard/elegant way to copy the original string to the dynamic memory, except for the below one? It is really important to me to use `realloc()` and not `malloc() + memcpy()`

```
int len = strlen(my_str);
char *new_str = (char*)malloc(len + 1);
memcpy(new_str, my_str, len + 1);
```

Comment: You cannot `realloc` a constant string. You will need to copy it and modify that.

Comment: The fundamental rule of `realloc` is *only `realloc` something that was `malloc`d in the first place*. You're breaking that rule. If it hurts when you do that, don't do that.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: I know. And it can also be a pointer that was `calloc`d. Let's not confuse the issue further with obscure details when the user doesn't have the basics down yet.

Comment: Why not to write these comments as answers and rate this question with better rate? Don't you think it's good that other programmers would see that this use case is not possible?

Comment: @EricLippert sure but it is not just for the OP, it should be for everyone reading the question.

Comment: Possibly related: [Are string literals const?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493139/are-string-literals-const)

Comment: @user3322273  You wrote "It is really important to me to use realloc() and not malloc() + memcpy()"  Why???

Comment: Nevermind, I delete this post. It is indeed not possible and not helpful. EDIT: oops, can't delete it :)

Comment: It's amazing how many wrong answers such a simple question elicits...

Comment: @EricLippert:  You can properly `realloc` anything created by `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc`, and `strdup`, but not `alloca`.  Are there other functions?

Comment: Apparently there is also `asprintf` and `vasprintf`... maybe even more?

Answer (score 3):

The question code:

```
char *my_str = "Hello World";
```

assigns the pointer 'my_str' to point at a static string which is not part of the "heap" from where memory is allocated.  Only  memory allocated from the "heap" can be resized with 'realloc()', or eventually returned to the heap using 'free()';

If you replace the code with:

```
char *my_str = strdup("Hello World");
```

Now the pointer 'my_str" is pointing to memory allocated from the heap, and it can be resized as indicated in the question code:

```
my_str = realloc(my_str, 50);
```

Remember to free this allocated memory when it is no longer needed:

```
free(my_str);
```

Comment: Concise and well stated.

Comment: +1, but I would add to it: Since the OP had some difficulty with the concept of heap memory, it's worth pointing out explicitly that now the pointer must be free()d.