# Unsigned char vs char in C — comparison of strings

Tags: c, string

I have a small assignment to do in C and I tried to find the best way I can to compare two strings (char arrays of course since strings are not defined in C).

This is my code :

```
int equal(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    int a = 0;
    while(!(a = *(unsigned char *)s1 - *(unsigned char *)s2) && *s2) ++s1,  ++s2;
    return (a == 0) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

It works but I don't see why I have to convert my char to an unsigned char.

(Of course I cannot use `<string.h>` in my assignment.)

Comment: Why are you using `unsigned char` in the first place? I don't think you need to...

Comment: Also, why is the code so complicated?  Just do one thing on each line

Comment: @Cornstalks That's his question lol

Comment: Why do you think you need the `(unsigned char *)` casts?  The code will work exactly the same without them.  The only time you need to convert to `unsigned` is if you have a possibility of overflow or values that are out of range for a particular signed type.

Comment: @user9000: I know, but my question is part of [rubber duck debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). I'm asking why the OP did it at all in the first place, to try and understand where the flaw in his logic is.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Well if I remove (unsigned char *), I just end up with an infinite loop.

Comment: @TivBroc: no you don't, or at least not from the casts.  If you're seeing an infinite loop, you must be doing something else different, like leaving off the parentheses around the assignment, or the `!`

Comment: @ChrisDodd Yeah I think it is when I call the function because I use : if(equal(argv[1], "factorial")). That is why ! Thanks for your answer ;)

Comment: @ChrisDodd  "only time you need to convert to `unsigned` is if you have a possibility of overflow or values that are out of range" does not sound correct. (unless `char` and `int` are the same size - maybe that is it)  Otherwise this code's subtraction does not benefit (or not) by casting to `unsigned char`.

Comment: @chux: that's why the casts are unneeded in this code -- there's no possibility of overflow, so they make no difference.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Ah,  I _do_ see the reason for the casts now: "there's no possibility of overflow` may not be so.  Check my answer's #6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The original code is fairly optimal.  For simple equality comparisons, there is no need for the `(unsigned char *)` casts. The following works fine.  (but see point #6):

   ```
   int equal(char *s1, char *s2) {
     int a = 0;
     while(!(a = *s1 - *s2) && *s2) ++s1, ++s2;
     return (a == 0) ? 1 : 0;
   }
   ```
2. In making more optimal code, there is no need to compare both strings for the null character `'\0'` as in `if (*s1 || *s2) ...`.  As code checks for a non-zero `a`, checking only 1 string is sufficient.
3. "... of course since strings are not defined in C" is not so.  C does define "string", though not as a type :

   > "A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character"  C11 §7.1.1 1
4. Using `(unsigned char *)` make sense if code is attempting to not only simply compare equality, but order.  Even in this case, the type could be `char`.  But by casting to `unsigned char` or even `signed char`, code provides consistent results across platforms even where some have `char` as `signed char` and others as `unsigned char`.

   ```
   // return 0, -1 or +1
   int order(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
     const unsigned char *uc1 = (const unsigned char *) s1;
     const unsigned char *uc2 = (const unsigned char *) s2;

     while((*uc1 == *uc2) && *uc1) ++uc1, ++uc2;
       return (*uc1 > *uc2) - (*uc1 < *uc2);
   }
   ```
5. <strike>Using `const` in the function signature allows code to be used with `const char *` as `order(buffer, "factorial");`.  Otherwise calling OP's `equal(char *s1, char *s2)` with `equal(buffer, "factorial");` is undefined behavior.</strike>  The stricken text would be true if the routine modified `*s1` or `*s2`, but it does not.  Using `const` does reduce certain warnings and allow for some optimizations.  Credit: @abligh

---

6. This **is** a corner case where the casting is needed.  If range of `char` is the same as the range of `int` (some graphics processors do that) and `char` is a `signed char`, then `*s1 - *s2` *can* overflow and that is undefined behavior (UB).  Of course, platforms that have the same range for `char` and `int` are rare.  IMO, it is doubtful even on such machines, a non-casted version of this code would fail, but it is technically UB.

Comment: Actually I think the original code has a bug in as does your simplification and your second example. Consider s1=`abcd` and s2=`abc` (original code and your simplification) or s1=`abc` and s2=`abcd` (second example).

Comment: Also could you cite a reference for the UB claims (not disupting - for my interest). I thought subtraction of 2 signed `char`s was defined even with overflow. If a signed char is the same length as an `int`, promotion to an `int` should also be unproblematic too. So as far as I can see there is no case where there is UB here (the subtraction may not give you what you intended but will still only give zero if the two `char`s are the same) ...

Comment: .. and re the other UB, why is *reading* from a `const char *` in the BSS cast to a `char *` UB? I thought in C (as opposed to C++) string literals were *not* `const` even though you can't write to them - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493139/are-string-literals-const - am I wrong here? Obviously `const` is a good idea for optimisation of the caller.

Comment: @abligh Both OP and this answer work with testing only 1 string for length termination as the final result depend on another comparison for the final result value.

Comment: @abligh in the case of a `signed char` and `int` having the same range: OP entire question hangs on `(int) - (int)`.  In a pathological situation  where code is subtracting `char`s with the values `0x7FFFFFFF` and `0xFFFFFFFF` and the converted/promoted to `int`,  the subtraction result arithmetically overflows and that is UB for signed integer math.  In theory - I agree with the likely  "the subtraction may not give you what you intended but will still only give zero if the two chars are the same", but the C spec does not provide that exception, it simply says on overflow, the result is UB.

Comment: @abligh Agree about `const` and UB - post amened.

Comment: Ah, because in C *signed* integer overflow is undefined behaviour as per C99 standard §3.4.3/1 - I agree.

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
int equal(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; s1[i] || s2[i]; i++)
        if (s1[i] != s2[i])
            return 0;
    return 1;   
}
```

Or if you prefer `while` loops:

```
int equal(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    while (*s1 || *s2)
        if (*s1++ != *s2++)
            return 0;
    return 1;   
}
```

To answer your specific question, in order to compare two strings (or indeed two characters) there is no need to convert them to `unsigned char`. I hope you agree my method is a little more readable than yours.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I tried to optimized something that should not have to.

Comment: Any compiler with even a trivial optimiser will only load `s1[i]` and `s2[i]` once in the above. There's not much more optimisation one can do.

Comment: Suggest simplification: `for (i=0; s1[i]; i++)`

Comment: @chux - that would falsely return equality if s1 was `abc` and s2 was `abcd`.

Comment: @abligh Agree about that my suggested simplification would not work.  What I meant was `for (i=0; s1[i]; i++)` and then return `*s1 == *s2`.  This would reduce the number of compares in the loop, yet add 1 compare at the end of the loop.