# How can I pass a string value to a function in C

Tags: c, string

This bothers me. It gives me a warning of

```
passing argument 1 of ‘funcName’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
```

however, the program to run just fine and printing the submitted value.

The functions are the following

```
void funcName(char *str) {
    printf("%s", str);
}

void main() {
    funcName("Hello world");
}
```

output is Hello world.

Comment: How did you get that warning? Please post the compilation line!

Comment: @Sleek 13-- Your issue has to do with which compiler warnings are enabled. String literals are not `const`, but are of type `char []`. It is UB to modify a string literal, and with GCC the flag `-Wwrite-strings` enables this warning. What compiler are you using, and what is the invocation?

Answer (score 5):

It's because `"Hello, world"` is constant, so change the function to

```
void funcName(const char *text) 
{
    printf("%s\n", text);
}
```

String literals are constant, they are stored in a read only memory section of your program, passing the pointer without `const` means that you can accidentally modify it inside the target function, if you do so, that would cause *undefined behavior*, and the compiler is trying to protect you from that.

Also, `void main()` is not a standard compliant valid signature for `main()`, you can find it in old books, previous to the standard, but now it's no longer accepted, accepted and standard signatures are

- `int main(void)` If you don't handle command line arguments.
- `int main(int argc, char **argv)` To handle `argc` parameteres stored in `argv` that where passed in the command line.

Comment: I get no warnings in GCC 4.9 with `gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` for OP's original code (with fixed signature for `main()` and added `#include <stdio.h>`).

Comment: At least a warning for `void main()`! Should be an error I think if `-std=c99` is passed.

Comment: @DavidBowling In fact this one `error: return type of 'main' is not 'int' [-Werror=main]`, and it's directly an error, not a warning.

Comment: Yes, I get warnings for `void main()`, and the missing `#include`; I mean, when I fix those, I see no warning for discarding `const`.

Comment: Adding the `-Wwrite-strings` flag triggers the warning; [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493139/are-string-literals-const) discusses the issue a bit, and there is a suggestion that `g++` enables this warning by default. But, I don't think there is a  problem passing a string literal into a function as `char *`, even though it is UB to modify a string literal.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the problem is that this C program is compiled as a C++ program.

In C++ string literals have types of constant character arrays. So if in a C++ program you supply a string literal as an argument to a function that has the corresponding parameter without the qualifier const then the compiler will issue a message.

If to compile the program as a C program then the code is valid because in C string literals have types of non-constant character arrays and the compiler should not issue a diagnostic message relative to qualifiers.

Nevertheless in any case it is better to declare the function like

```
void funcName( const char *str );
               ^^^^^^
```

because in this case the user of the function can be sure that the string passed to the function will not be changed.

Take into account that function main without parameters shall be declared in C like

```
int main( void )
```

Comment: Despite a couple of requests, OP has not provided details of compilation. Nonetheless, I believe that this is the correct answer, and you have my UV. It seems an important detail, which you mention, that strings in C are _not_ `const`. I did try to compile OP code with g++, and got `warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]`; not exactly the warning mentioned by OP, but related.