# C - initializer not constant with string literal

Tags: c

I am aware of the limitations for initializers at file-scope in c: you cannot use a variable (even const), functions etc... But I really do not understand why this does not work:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//unsigned long a = "string"[0] > '0'; // this does not compile
unsigned long a = 's' > '0'; // this works fine, output is "a = 1"

int main(void)
{
    printf("a = %lu\n",a);

    return 0;
}
```

Why does the line with the string literal gives: error: initializer element is not constant. Are string literals not considered constant? Is there any way to make it work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493139/are-string-literals-const

Comment: "constant" is a vague term. C uses several related concepts. The one you need is *constant expression*. A subscript  expression like `something[other]` is never a constant expression.

Comment: Please supply some details about the background story, as this is likely to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I would like to use a custom macro that computes a unix timestamp from __DATE__ and __TIME__ and assign that value to a global variable at file scope. The simple fix is to hide that variable in a function but I think it is ugly and I was curious as to *why* it does not compile.

Answer (score 9):

Your variable has static storage duration, as such and according to N1570 (C11) [§6.7.9/p4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p4):

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or
>   thread storage duration shall be constant expressions or string
>   literals.

String literals have static storage duration <sup>[§6.4.5/p6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p6)</sup>, so their *addresses* can be considered constant expressions (which is why they are allowed as initializers). But you are trying to access the value at such an address, and the C standard explicitly forbids it. To quote [§6.6/p9](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.6p9), emphasis mine:

> An address constant is a null pointer, a pointer to an lvalue
>   designating an object of static storage duration, or a pointer to a
>   function designator; it shall be created explicitly using the unary &
>   operator or an integer constant cast to pointer type, or implicitly by
>   the use of an expression of array or function type. **The
>   array-subscript [] and member-access . and -> operators, the address &
>   and indirection * unary operators, and pointer casts may be used in
>   the creation of an address constant, but the value of an object shall
>   not be accessed by use of these operators.**

On the other hand, when you used character **constants** for comparison, you obtain a valid constant expression.

Comment: *String literals have static storage duration* Can you quote standard on that?

Comment: @user694733 C11 6.7.9/4 and C11 6.4.5/6.

Comment: @user694733 - See [§6.4.5/p6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p6) for the definition of a string literals. They are all stand-ins for arrays with static storage duration that contains the literals content.

Comment: I am an adding a different view on this question. Will delete it if it misses something. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @coderredoc Why would he mind? you don't have to ask!

Comment: @coderredoc  - I always advocate for answer diversity. It's part of SO's strength

Comment: @machine_1.: Ah just mentioned. And thanks StoryTeller.

Answer (score 4):

In C language objects with static storage duration have to be initialized with constant expressions or with aggregate initializers containing constant expressions.

Now here you had basically `"string"[0]` as an constant expression? But is it so?

The thing is From 6.6p2

> A constant expression can be evaluated during translation rather than runtime, and accordingly may be used in any place that a constant may be.

Now after that I checked the [translation phases](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.2) and what it consists of:
It will be clear that none of the expression is evaluated which involves a `[]` array subscripting over string literal. This literally involves dereferencing an address and getting the vlaue which is not possible to do in translation phases. That's why this error.