# How to change character in a string?

Tags: c

I want to have a function that receives a string as a parameter and change symbols of the string

`char *strChanger(char *str)`.

I tried to implement it like this:

```
char *strChanger(char *str) {
    if(str[0] != '\0') {
        str[0] = 'a';
    }
    return str;
}
```

In the program it should look like `char *newstr = strChanger("hi");`

But when I try to change a character in the string, a program chrashes.

I did some experiments and find that:

```
// Works fine
char str[] = "hi";
str[0] = 'a';

// Crashes
char *str = "hi";
str[0] = 'a';
```

I dont understand the difference. Why the second block of code doesn't work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493139/are-string-literals-const

Comment: `char* str = "hi"` sets str to point to read-only memory.

Comment: @BoPersson and @Anders K. both makes good points. `char str[]` is on the stack (hence you can modify each character), while `char *str` if you think about is just a pointer that might or might not point to a modifiable memory region. In your case it was a non modifiable memory region (read-only as @Anders K. pointed out).

Comment: @AndersK. Detail: C does not require any "read-only" memory.  C does say that attempting to modify a _string literal_ is UB.

Comment: @chux a literal may not be altered i.e. read-only

Comment: @AndersK. In C, attempting to alter a _string literal_ is UB - it should not be attempted.  It might work it might not.  C does not require a _string literal_ to be read-only.  "If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
undefined."   §6.4.5 7.   OTOH, Attempting to change a _compound literal_ is not a problem.

Comment: @chux *treating* it as read-only should solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because modifying string literal is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) - in your case leading to crash of your program.

In the second example, you are passing the string literal direclty and tried to make changes to it. Speaking in terms of `char *newstr = strChanger("hi")`.

In fact `char *str = "hi";` is basically making `str` point to the string literal. More specifically [string literal is an array](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p6) which is converted into pointer to the first element and which is then assigned to `str`. Then you tried to modify it - which is undefined behavior.

In the first case a copy of it is made which is modifiable and you can make changes to it which is then passed and it worked. You are declaring a char array and initializing it with the content of the string literal.

If you have POSIX defined `"strdup"` then you can do this

```
char *newstr = strChanger(strdup("hi"));
```

But again then inside `strChanger` you need to check the passed value - `strdup` may return `NULL` in case it fails to allocate memory and provide you with the copied string. At some point after using like this you will have to free the memory - `free(newstr)`.

From standard [6.4.5p7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p7) under string literal

> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the appropriate values. *If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.*

From [6.7.9p14](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p14) under initialization

> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF-8 string literal, optionally enclosed in braces. *Successive bytes of the string literal (including the terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the elements of the array.*