# printf doesn't always print correctly

Tags: c, substring

I know this question was asked here several times. I followed methods mentioned like initialize variable `start` (`int start = 0`), or typecast it to `int` in `printf` statement.

But these methods do not help. So I open up this post to ask this question again.

My program is to return a substring from a user input source string. My method works. Only `printf` doesn't work.

I write up this method.

```
char *GetSubstring(const char source[], int start, int count, char result[])
{
    if ((size_t)start > strlen(source)) {
        *result = 0;
    } else {
        if ((size_t)(start + count) > strlen(source)) {
            count = strlen(source) - start;
        }
        while (start > 0) {
            source++;
            start--;
        }
        *(result + count) = 0;

        while ( count > 0 || *(source + count) != 0 ) {
            count--;
            *(result + count) = *(source + count);
        }
    }
    return(result);
}
```

If I hard code all parameters, the print statements work fine.

```
int main(void)
{
    char source[100] = "abcdefg";
    char result[100];
    int start = 2;
    int count = 3;

    printf("%s %d %d\n", source, start, count); //all correct
    printf("%s %d %d %s\n", source, start, count,
           GetSubstring(source,start,count,result));//all correct

    return 0;
}
```

However if I get parameters from user input. 'start' in 1st `printf` statement prints out correctly. But it prints out as garbage in the second `printf` statement. Other parameters print out correct.

```
int main(void)    
{
    char source[100];
    char result[100];
    int start = 0;
    int count = 0;

    printf("enter source\n");
    fgets(source, 100, stdin);
    source[strcspn(source, "\n")] = '\0';

    printf("enter start and count\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &start, &count);

    printf("%s %d %d\n", source, start, count); //all correct
    //'start' print out as 1650524162, rest parameters correct
    printf("%s %d %d %s\n", source, start, count,
           GetSubstring(source,start,count,result));

    return 0;
}
```

The problem may have to do with type casting `(size_t)start` in my method `GetSubstring`. But I need to do that for comparison with `strlen(source)`.

Please let me know any suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Make sure you terminate the substring with a '\0' character before feeding it to printf

Comment: `(size_t)start` - Ugh, don't do such casts.

Comment: The casts is not a problem here, but they indicate another problem. The right way to correct it is not by casting, but in stead making `start` and `count` of type `size_t`

Comment: Related about casting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62563330/6699433

Comment: @KiJéy, `*(result + count) = 0;` does that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the `size_t` cast though you could make those variables `size_t` and avoid casting altogether, [like @klutt sugested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62986615/printf-doesnt-always-print-correctly/62986773#comment111385258_62986773), and use `%zu` format specifier in `printf` and `scanf`.

The issue you complain about lies in this cycle:

```
while ( count > 0 || *(source + count) != 0 )
{
     count--;
     *(result + count) = *(source + count);
     printf("%s %d %d\n", source, start, count);
}
```

As you use `||` in the condition, `count` will be allowed to be negative, which in term allows for negative indexing of `source` which in term invokes undefined behavior.

Another problem which is not apparent in the test case is the limit case, if you provide the parameters `2` and `5`, the result should be `cdefg` and it's not, the conditon is not met and the cycle is never executed.

I believe what you need is:

```
while ( count > 0 && *(source + count - 1) != 0 ) { /*...*/ }
                  ^^                  ^^^
```

AFAICT that second condition is unneeded anyway so you could remove it and have only:

```
 while ( count > 0) { /*...*/ }
```

[Live demo](https://onlinegdb.com/H1Ei2AGgv)

Comment: The cast is not THE issue, but it is an issue