# Cast function argument passed by rereference in C

Tags: c, floating-point, type-conversion, integer, function-definition

I have the following function. It works with `short`:

```
void foo (short n, short * res)
{
  *res = n*2;
}
```

I want to store the result in `double` variable. For example:

```
short in = 5;
double out = 0;
foo(in,&out);
```

But in that way the result is some garbage. Is there a way to cast these types in such situation, or the only solution is to use some temp variable of type `short`?

Comment: Use a variable of the correct type in the call, and then assign to the final destination variable.

Comment: Regarding casting, it's not some "magical" thing that will make things right. Rather it's a way to trick, fool and even *lie* to the compiler about the type of some expression. And the compiler is stupid, it will believe what you tell it, even when it's not true (like when telling it that this "pointer to `double`" should be treated as "pointer to `short`").

Comment: By the way, what is the purpose of the function returning an `int`, and always returning `0`? If you don't actually *return* the calculated value, then the function should have the return type `void`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, in this particular example returning such `int` is of no use, it's a leftover of the original function, that was simplified for the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you cannot change the function, then I would do something like this:

```
short in = 5;
short tmp;
double out;
foo(in,&tmp);
out = tmp;
```

If you do this a lot, consider writing a wrapper as @einpoklum did in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63773195/6699433) like this:

```
void foo_wrapper(short n, double *out)
{
    short tmp;
    foo(n, &tmp);
    out = tmp;
}
```

I guess it could theoretically be possible with casting, but I would advice against it. The risks of doing it wrong is high, and you might get hard chased bugs, and if you do explicit casts, the compiler will not give you warnings. I wrote a rant about casting in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62563330/6699433)

In this particular case, note that the function `foo` have no idea of the resulting type. So you will need a temporary variable. You could get rid of that by using the `out` variable as it's own temporary variable with some casting **but I strongly advice against it!**

```
short in = 5;
double out;
foo(in, (short*)&out);
out = *(short*)&out; // Evil! Avoid code like this!
printf("%f\n", out);
```

This works on my machine, but it does violate aliasing rules as @chqrlie wrote in comments. Do NOT do like this!

@chqrlie also wrote an alternative approach with no extra variable and no evil casting. It works, but UGH! Don't do like this either:

```
short in = 5; 
foo(in, &in); // No! Just don't!
out = in;
```

Of course it will not work if you need the original value, but that's pretty obvious. The major flaw here is that it's just plain bad. Don't reuse variables for different purposes just to get rid of a temporary variable.

Comment: *I guess it could theoretically be possible with casting* not in this particular case: th encoding of `short` and `double` are too different for a casting approach.

Comment: @chqrlie I did a solution with evil casting ;)

Comment: interesting! this solution violates the aliasing rules. It also assumes that `short` does not have stricter alignment requirements than `double`, which is a fair assumption only defeated on a perverse DS9K :) a simpler one is this: `short in = 5; foo(in, &in); out = in;`

Comment: @chqrlie nice way :) unfortunately, not all the time, as in some cases it is needed to keep original data safe

Comment: @chqrlie Your suggestion hurt my eyes. :D But I updated the answer. Good one.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @klutt's valid [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63773195/1593077), remember that if you do on many occasions, it's usually a good idea to wrap the whole thing in a function:

```
int foo_d (short n, double * result)
{
  short result_inner;
  int retval = foo(n, &result_inner);
  *result = (double) result_inner;
    // Note to @Ans-lte: The explicit cast here isn't necessary,
    // the conversion will happen anyway.
  return retval;
}
```

Comment: The cast in `*result = (double) res_inner` isn't needed, that conversion will happen implicitly anyway.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Yes, I just wanted to be explicit.

Comment: `auto retval` is not idiomatic in C and has a different meaning from its C++ usage, it defines `retval` as `int` regardless of the type of the initializer. it is much less confusing to specify the type explicitly as `int retval`.

Comment: Explicit casts when not needed is evil. Avoid that. The only thing you accomplish is to hide warnings if not done right, and it gives zero value. Also, your use of auto is COMPLETELY non-ideomatic. There's never a good reason to use that keyword in C, even if it does work in this particular case.

Comment: @klutt: Sorry, edited. It's the C++ author in me :-(

Comment: I assumed that. You can also rewrite it so that it does not return anything. The original question is edited, and the return value was not relevant to the question.

Comment: On top of that, a variable is incorrectly spelled, so this would not compile.

Comment: And that explicit cast... If you change it to the incorrect cast `(char) res_inner`, then you will get wrong results for `foo_d(200, &out)`

Answer (score 1):

Using casting is a bad idea.

For starters it is unclear why you want to use a float type instead of an  integer type as for example `int` or `long int`.

If the statement

```
*res = n*2;
```

can produce an overflow for an object of the type `short` then you should rewrite the function like

```
void foo (short n, int * res)
{
  *res = n * 2;
}
```

Pay attention to that the result of the expression `n * 2` already has the type `int` in your original function.

If the problem is not related to the overflow then why not just to write

```
short res;

foo( n, &res );

double d = res;
```

Or again you need to rewrite the function like

```
void foo (short n, double * res)
{
  *res = n * 2.0;
}
```

But in any case do not use any casting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but working with `short` types function and `double` variable with result are "tools" of the project which I have to use with no changes of their types

Comment: @Ans-lte As I wrote in this case just assign the object res to an object of the type double.