# My compiler returned "assignment to 'int *' from incompatible pointer type 'char *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]" when I ran my C program

Tags: c, compiler-errors, clang, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char grade = 'A';
    int *p = &grade;
    printf("The address where the grade is stored: %p\n", p);
    printf("Grade: %c\n", grade);
    return 0;
}
```

I get this error each time I compile the code on VScode but never on code blocks.

```
warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'int *' with an
      expression of type 'char *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    int *p = &grade;
         ^   ~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
 ./main
The address where the grade is stored: 0x7ffc3bb0ee2b
Grade: A"
```

Comment: It's telling you that you're trying to make an integer pointer `p` point to a *character* `grade`; those aren't compatible.

Comment: Suggestions on how I can correct such?

Comment: The message in the title is from a different code.

Comment: use `char *` instead of `int *` for storing `&grade`

Comment: Since `grade` is of type `char`, then a pointer to `grade` (which is what `&grade` is) must be of type `char *`. Which is what the error message is telling you ("incompatible pointer types initializing 'int *' with an **expression of type 'char *'**" (emphasis mine)).

Comment: Also note that the `printf` format `%p` really expects a value of type `void *`. If you want to be proper you should cast the type: `printf("...", (void *) p);`. Or use `void *` for the type of `p` to begin with: `void *p = &grade;`.

Comment: Thanks folks. I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

The warning tells you exactly what it is. It says:

> incompatible pointer types initializing 'int *' with an expression of type 'char *'

This means that `p` is of type `int *`, that `&grade` is of type `char *`, and that these two pointers are not compatible. The solution is to change the declaration of `p` to:

```
char *p = &grade;
```

One more thing. Usually you can safely do implicit conversions to and from any pointer to `void *`, but not when passed as argument to a variadic function. If you want to print the address, use this:

```
printf("%p", (void *)p);
```

But only cast when needed. Never do it just to get rid of warnings. Here is an answer I wrote about that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62563330/6699433

As an alternative, you could use a void pointer directly:

```
void *p = &grade;
printf("%p", p);
```

But then you would need to cast if you want to dereference it. For example:

```
char c = *(char*)p;
```

That cast is not necessary if `p` is declared as `char *`.